# How to execute a shell script after spacemacs completes loading?

Tags: shell, emacs, spacemacs

I use **EXWM** and wanted to execute a shell script after the startup.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I achieved it.

- Go to the `dotspacemacs/user-config` method
- add this part of the code in there,

  ```
  (use-package exwm
    :config
    (call-process "/bin/bash" "~/path/to/script.sh"))
  ```

  [ **Note:** One thing to keep in mind is that the user-config loads after spacemacs finish loading all the packages. ]
- You can execute a shell script after loading any package following a similar step. You just have to change the package name after the `use-package` which is `exwm` in my case.